# Why isn't there an Enum instance for Sum and Product?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

If you import [`Data.Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Monoid.html), you'll find that [`Sum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Sum), [`Product`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Product), [`All`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:All), [`Any`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Any) don't have `Enum` instances, even though `Bool` and instances of `Integral` do. Wouldn't it make sense to provide an instance, say, `Enum a => Enum (Sum a)`? Is there any theoretical reason for not doing that? I would also appreciate links that go deep into theory behind this.

Comment: Maybe they simply forgot. There are already instances for the standard classes, except `Enum`. (I wonder if all those instances are actually useful in practice, though.)

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it make sense to provide these instances? Not really a lot. The purpose of those newtypes is that you can use a concrete number type in a function that wants to deal with a generic `Monoid` instance. The idea is, you wrap the arguments in the newtype constructor, apply the `Monoid`-polymorphic function (which doesn't know it's merely dealing with wrapped numbers), and immediately unwrap the result again. You don't do anything else with `Sum`, `Product`, `Any` etc. values, thus you also should't need an `Enum` instance.

The only reason you *could* need it is if a function had the constraint `(Monoid a, Enum a) => ...`. But that's an unlikely combination ­– `Monoid` is a general, high-level, “algebraic” class, whereas `Enum` is a rather low-level, specific, set-ish class. If you require `Enum` it means you'll deal more or less just with a range of `Int`s, and will ascribe your own meaning to “zero element” and “element combination”, so why would you also require `Monoid`?

But should you ever find yourself in that situation, you can just locally define a newtype and give it precisely the instances you need. At some point this ad-hoc approach is more efficient than preemptively defining standard instances for *every conceivable combination* of constraints to types, which in most cases nobody will ever need.

Comment: If that is indeed the argument then why does [`Alt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Alt) have an `Enum` instance?

Comment: You write that "`Enum` is a rather low-level, specific, set-ish class". I think you praise it too highly. `Enum` is a *completely broken* class.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @chi that somebody just forgot. I can't think of a good reason it shouldn't be there, which is reason enough (people are likely defining orphan instances in their application code, which leads to sadness).

Comment: The main reason against it is YAGNI, and build times. If everything new is always cross-instantiated with everything else, we get a quadratic increase in the number of instances. And while I agree that it can make sense to pre-emptively add instances for important types that actually turn up in module interfaces, this does not apply for `Sum` etc. because these are pure “local dictionary proxy” types. Instead of defining orphan instances, people can (and should!) just define their own newtypes for the rare circumstances when the standard ones with their existing instances don't do the trick.

Comment: "because these are pure “local dictionary proxy” types" I disagree that there's really a meaningful distinction between newtype wrapper types like `Product` and other more "respectable" types for which you might define a `Monoid` instance say